# Firefox: drawImage(video) fails with NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE: Component is not available

Tags: javascript, firefox, video, canvas, getusermedia

Trying to call `drawImage` with a `video` whose source is a webcam feed seems to fail in Firefox with an
`NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE: Component is not available`.

I have tried to wait for every event the video tag fires: `play`, `playing`, `canplay`, `loadeddata`, `loadedmetadata`, and so on, and nothing works. This seems to be because these events are firing before the stream is properly loaded into the `<video>` element.

[JSFiddle with error](http://jsfiddle.net/qPce4/) (You can view the error in the console)

A side effect is that the width and height of the video is also incorrect.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=879717) in Firefox. The easiest fix is to simply keep trying until the error goes away, since no event fires at the correct time.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/9aT63/25/

Basically, you have to wrap the `drawImage` call in a try/catch block.

```
function drawVideo() {
  try {
    $vidCanvasCtx.drawImage($vid, 0, 0, $vidCanvas.width, $vidCanvas.height);
    ...
  } catch (e) {
    if (e.name == "NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE") {
      // Wait a bit before trying again; you may wish to change the
      // length of this delay.
      setTimeout(drawVideo, 100);
    } else {
      throw e;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, sadly I have to wait for a few more hours before I can

Comment: I am using firefox v33.0 and they still haven't solved this bug.
Also, using the try catch block makes it painfully slow on firefox.

Comment: this didn't work for me, using an image instead of a video, and kept looping infinitely.

Comment: While the bug linked in this answer is closed, this still appears to be a thing according to [another bugzilla entry](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1481406#c2) that was previously posted as an answer by another user.