# How to create thumbnail for video on Firefox for Android

Tags: javascript, android, firefox, firefox-android

I am looking for a method to generate thumbnail in Firefox for Android. I found some resources regarding this topic: [Create thumbnail from video file via file input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23640869/create-thumbnail-from-video-file-via-file-input). But Firefox for Android always throws `NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE` when calling `drawImage(HTMLVideoElement, int, int, int, int)`.

The example attached in the SO post can be used to reproduce this issue: https://codepen.io/aertmann/pen/mAVaPx. The example throws on Firefox for Android while it works on Mac and iOS (afaik it is a downgraded version of Safari). According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage, `NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE` is thrown when resource is not loaded. However, even when I try to do it after `loadedmetadata` and `loadeddata` or follow another similar question on SO ([Firefox: drawImage(video) fails with NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE: Component is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18580844/firefox-drawimagevideo-fails-with-ns-error-not-available-component-is-not-av)) to retry until success, it still doesn’t work.

Comment: What is Firefox Android  can you explain.

Comment: Idk what u mean, the tag is probably auto suggested, for "Firefox for Android" I meant this: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mozilla.firefox

Comment: "Firefox for Android" is what Mozilla refers to their own product, Android version of Firefox

Comment: Ok, I saw it, typo 

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1526207
filed a bug to mozilla, appears to be a bug of firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opened an issue on Bugzilla: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1526207
Most probably firefox issue